# I'm new in codewars and i don't understand why my solution is not correct

Tags: python

I wrote a working code without any bugs, and the result is the same as it is shown in the sample, but codewars is not accepting my solution, and i did not get why it is not correct.

Here is the kata from codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5842df8ccbd22792a4000245

Here is my code:

```
def expanded_form(num):
    lenght = list(str(num))
    num_list = []
    ten = 10
    final = ''
    
    for i in lenght:
        
        result = num % ten
        num -= result
        ten = ten * 10
        
        if result > 0:
            
            num_list.append(str(result))
            
    num_list.reverse()
    
    for j in range(len(num_list)):
        
        if j == len(num_list) - 1:
            final += num_list[j]
            
        else:
            final += num_list[j] + ' + '
        
    print(final)
```

I have no clue what's wrong, so i can't move forward.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, 'return final' was enough to make it relevant <3

Answer (score -2):

Your method is cluttered a lot, I can not truly understand your intentions so I have majorly refactored your code.

```py
def expanded_form(num):
    numsplitted = list(map(int, str(num)))  # Convert the input to separate int digits
    ten = 1  # 10 to the power 0
    
    for i in range(len(numsplitted)-1, -1, -1):  # We reverse it to start from the ones place.
        numsplitted[i] = numsplitted[i] * ten
        ten *= 10  # Increase 10's power by multiplying by 10
        
    while 0 in numsplitted:  # There are 0 in our list
        numsplitted.remove(0)

    return ' + '.join(map(str, numsplitted))  # Finally convert all values to a string and join them with ' + '
```

Comment: Thank you Amaank, but the thing with return istead of print was anough and codewars accepted my code :]